# How to put logout in action bar menu

Tags: android

I used to use a logout button to logout when pressed on an activity but now I am willing to put it at action bar menu. I don't know how to do it.

What I want to do: A user if presses logout on the right action bar menu, he should log out of the app.

This is the code that I always use to have logout on button press (consider that activity page has only logout button):

```
public class Activity_Main extends Activity {

private Button btnLogout;
private SQLiteHandler db;
private SessionManager session;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }

    // Logout button click event
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            logoutUser();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
 * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
 * */
private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);

    db.deleteUsers();

    // Launching the login activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Main.this, Activity_Login.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Currently the action bar menu has two item more apps and rate apps which redirect to google play..I want to replace more app with logout action.

This is what I want to modify:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.rate_app:
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName())));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName())));
        }
        return true;
    case R.id.more_app:
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getString(R.string.more_apps))));
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is the menu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_ab_overflow_compat"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="">
    <menu>

        <!-- Rate App -->
        <item
            android:id="@+id/rate_app"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            android:title="@string/rate"/>

        <!-- More App -->
        <item
            android:id="@+id/more_app"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            android:title="@string/more"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your menu.xml file, I assume you have something  like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/rate_app"
    android:title="@string/rate_app"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="showIfRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:title="@string/logout"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="showIfRoom" />
```

Now, in your `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu), switch like you are already doing:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
   if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
      return true;
   }
   // Handle action bar actions click
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case R.id.rate_app:
     try {
         startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName())));
     } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName())));
    }
    return true;
   case R.id.action_logout:
    logoutUser();
    return true;
   default:
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

This should help you achieve what you need. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: If you got it working with this answer, please accept it so it will be marked as answered! I am glad it worked for you!

Comment: You kept it so simple. Great. Working. Accepted the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I am glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 1):

There is a menu.xml file with the Action Bar Buttons. You can replace any of the buttons for a logout button and the switch case controls which button is clicked.
Inside the correct case, add the code for your logout function.

Comment: You mean to say to do the same way I use to do using button?. I am new to android. can you show how to do in the above code. I will be thankful.

Comment: @Eenvincible's answer is pretty complete with the code you should use.

Comment: Yes, I got it working. Thank you for helping me out.